# More then items selector

Tags: html, css, selector

I want to select items based on how many divs the wrapper contains.
(if "FilterEquipmentByBarcodePage" contains more then 3 "form row")

[Here is the jsfiddle link:](https://jsfiddle.net/ux567zsz/#&togetherjs=FrOGNox7dP)

```
<div id="FilterEquipmentByBarcodePage">

  <div class="form_row">
    <div>
      <input type="Text" name="Summary" class="filter_summary_search_input">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form_row">
    <div>
      <input type="Text" name="Summary" class="filter_summary_search_input">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form_row">
    <div>
      <input type="Text" name="Summary" class="filter_summary_search_input">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want a pure css solution or javascript as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can affect items based on their quantity with CSS only with quantity queries.

[Here's a great article on quantity queries](http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css)

You'll want to use the `nth-last-child` selector with the quantity of `n`. In your case `n+4`.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/6q97e5ph/).

I'm not sure what you mean with you want to "select items". If my example above helps great, else try explaining what you want to do exactly and I might be able to update my code.

Comment: Really nice article. Did not even know that its possible, seems to be the answer. :-) Upvoted.

Comment: @DomeTune I didn't know either. And there I was thinking I wouldn't need math in "real life". You might like [this article](http://alistapart.com/article/using-css-mod-queries-with-range-selectors) too.

Comment: thanks for this article too. It is awesome, what we can do with pure css nowadays.

Comment: Thanks so much @PaulvandenDool